# Set limit feature_importances_ in DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to set a limit for my feature_importances_ output using DataFrame. 
Below is my code (refer from this [blog](https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/learning-decision-tree-in-scikit-learn-package/)):

```
train = df_visualization.sample(frac=0.9,random_state=639)
test = df_visualization.drop(train.index)

train.to_csv('train.csv',encoding='utf-8')
test.to_csv('test.csv',encoding='utf-8')

train_dis = train.iloc[:,:66]
train_val = train_dis.values
train_in = train_val[:,:65]
train_out = train_val[:,65]

test_dis = test.iloc[:,:66]
test_val = test_dis.values
test_in = test_val[:,:65]
test_out = test_val[:,65]

dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=59,criterion='entropy')
dt = dt.fit(train_in,train_out)

score = dt.score(train_in,train_out)
test_predicted = dt.predict(test_in)

# Print the feature ranking
print("Feature ranking:")

print (DataFrame(dt.feature_importances_, columns = ["Imp"], index = train.iloc[:,:65].columns).sort_values(['Imp'], ascending = False))
```

My problem now is it display all 65 features.
Output :

```
                                        Imp
wbc                                0.227780
age                                0.100949
gcs                                0.069359
hr                                 0.069270
rbs                                0.053418
sbp                                0.052067
Intubation-No                      0.050729
...                                     ...
Babinski-Normal                    0.000000
ABG-Metabolic Alkolosis            0.000000
ABG-Respiratory Acidosis           0.000000
Reflexes-Unilateral Hyperreflexia  0.000000
NS-No                              0.000000
```

For example I just want top 5 features only.
Expected output:

```
                                        Imp
wbc                                0.227780
age                                0.100949
gcs                                0.069359
hr                                 0.069270
rbs                                0.053418
```

**Update :**
I got the way to display using [itertuples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html).

```
display = pd.DataFrame(dt.feature_importances_, columns = ["Imp"], index = train.iloc[:,:65].columns).sort_values(['Imp'], ascending = False)
x=0
for row,col in display.itertuples():
    if x<5:
        print(row,"=",col)
    else:
        break
    x++
```

Output :

```
Feature ranking:
wbc = 0.227780409582
age = 0.100949241154
gcs = 0.0693593476192
hr = 0.069270425399
rbs = 0.0534175402602
```

But I want to know whether this is the efficient way to get the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
indices = np.argsort(dt.feature_importances_)[::-1]
for i in range(5): 
       print " %s = %s" % (feature_cols[indices[i]], dt.feature_importances_[indices[i]])
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Would you care to elaborate "[::-1]" part, or give any doc to refer?

Comment: About the efficiency(I mean faster in process the output), I record the time interval, here I got :

My method : 0.009999990463256836
Your method : 0.019999980926513672

My method more faster than yours.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the explanation. Sorry can't upvote for now since have not enough reputation score.